# NetBeans PHP formatting rules

Tags: php, formatting, netbeans-6.9

**How I can change NetBeans 6.9 formatting rule to change this autoformatting:**

```
if (true)
{
    if (true)
    {
    }if (true)
    {
    }$do_something_else;
}return;
```

**to**

```
if (true)
{
    if (true)
    {
    }
    if (true)
    {
    }
    $do_something_else;
}
return;
```

Unfortunately all code in php files saved in one line without spaces. And when I had saved NetBeans example code in the same one-line style and after press Alt+shift+F to format it(with this http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/customize-code-formatting-in-netbeans/ settings), I got some problem with absent new line after if close tag

Comment: Haha.. that question doesn't make too much sense without formatting :).. Why don't you select the text and press the {} (not in netbeans, here on stackoverflow)... the we can see what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to formate the file and use proper indentations , 
select all `ctrl`+`a` then select `Source > Formate` from the upper menu.

about missing tag and brackets , netbeans are awesome , just check `Tools > options`